# How to make an audio file wait for the end of another one in order to start them together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I'm trying to build a basic sampler. I have 4 different audio files (1 guitar, 1 drum, 1 piano and 1 bass).  The sound kit buttons programmed the way I want, but I cannot get the loops to work the way I want.

What i want to do is this :

- if the user clicks on a button it launches the sample
- if the user clicks again on the same button it stops the sample
- and if the user clicks  on another sample it waits for the end of the first sample and then start together

For now i manage to do the first and the second steps but i can't figure how to do the third one.

I tried to use Event Listener to know when a loop ends but i've never managed to make it work.

So my question is : is there an easy to do this third step ?
If you could give me a bit more detail when explaining, that would be great. Thanks!

Here what's my js look like so far :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var basse = {
    padOne:  new Audio('basse2.mp3'),
  };

  var drum = {
    padOne: new Audio('m1_drum1_85.mp3'),
  };

  var guitar = {
    padOne: new Audio('m1_guitare1_85.mp3'),
  };

  var piano = {
    padOne: new Audio('m1_piano_85.mp3'),
  };

  $('.pad-1').mousedown(function() {
    if (basse.padOne.paused) {
      basse.padOne.load()
      basse.padOne.loop = true;
      basse.padOne.play();
    } else {
      basse.padOne.pause();
      basse.padOne.currentTime = 0
    }
  });

  $('.pad-5').mousedown(function() {
    if (drum.padOne.paused) {
      drum.padOne.load()
      drum.padOne.loop = true;
      drum.padOne.play();
    } else {
      drum.padOne.pause();
      drum.padOne.currentTime = 0
    }
  });

  $('.pad-9').mousedown(function() {
    if (guitar.padOne.paused) {
      guitar.padOne.load()
      guitar.padOne.loop = true ;
      guitar.padOne.play();
    } else {
      guitar.padOne.pause();
      guitar.padOne.currentTime = 0
    }
  });

  $('.pad-13').mousedown(function() {
    if (piano.padOne.paused) {
      piano.padOne.load()
      piano.padOne.loop = true ;
      guitar.padOne.play();
    } else {
      piano.padOne.pause();
      piano.padOne.currentTime = 0
    }
  });
});
```